# The resource cannot be found HTTP 404 Error | HttpPost | HomeController.cs

Tags: c#, html, excel, database

I am working on my first webapplication and I am running into a problem that I can't solve.
I am using a ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) MVC and I want to get a button on my site where a user can upload their excel file and the excel file gets passed to a (local) SQL database. I can't get it to work, and I have watched 10 youtube videos and 20 different sites, but I cannot get it to work.

This is the code from the HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Xml;

namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string fileExtension =
                                         System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);
                    if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["file"].FileName;
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                        }
                        Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                        excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        //connection String for xls file format.
                        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                        {
                            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        //connection String for xlsx file format.
                        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                        excelConnection.Open();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        if (dt == null)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                        String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                        int t = 0;
                        //excel data saves in temp file here.
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            excelSheets[t] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            t++;
                        }
                        OleDbConnection excelConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

                        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", excelSheets[0]);
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection1))
                        {
                            dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
                        }
                    }
                    if (fileExtension.ToString().ToLower().Equals(".xml"))
                    {
                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["FileUpload"].FileName;
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                        }

                        Request.Files["FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation);
                        // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.ReadXml(xmlreader);
                        xmlreader.Close();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                        string query = "Insert into Person(Name,Email,Mobile) Values('" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "','" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "')";
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code from my Index.cshtml (I do not think you will need this, but better safe than sorry)

```
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

[image: The error that I get]

I have tried running only the html file (so with the default homecontroller.cs file) and that works, but when I add my code to the Homecontroller.cs it stops working.
I have no idea where to look.
Thanks for helping me in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add HttpGet action in HomeController.cs like below code so you will able to see your index page in browser and then able to perform any post actions.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
 return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed adding the get method in the controller which will return the view.

Add below method in the controller and it will open the Index page.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

Kindly mark as answer if it resolves your issue.